# PHPUnit setup and tearDown for test cases

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

PHPUnit has `setup` and `tearDown` events that run, respectively, before and after each test within a test case. In my specific scenario, I also want to run something like a `testCaseSetup` and `testCaseTearDown`. Is that possible?

Current solution looks like this:

```
<?php

class MyTestCase extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    public function __construct($name = NULL, array $data = array(), $dataName = '')
    {
        // My test case setup logic
        parent::__construct($name, $data, $dataName);
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        // My test case tear down logic
    }
}
```

But it seems far from optimal for the following reasons:

- I have to redeclare `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` construct and redirect any arguments. IF PHPUnit constructor is changed on a version update, my test case will stop.
- Probably `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` was not declared to be used like this.

I would like to know if there are better solutions. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there are special methods for that purpose: `setUpBeforeClass` and `tearDownAfterClass`.

```
class TemplateMethodsTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        // do sth before the first test
    } 

    public static function tearDownAfterClass()
    {
        // do sth after the last test
    }
```

Comment: Man, I searched through all the docs and couldn't find it. Thanks!